# Stuck on import wizard SQL Server 2008 R2 (from Excel)

Tags: sql, excel, import, sql-server-2008-r2, xlsx

I'm trying to import data from my excel file to a SQL Server database. Everything goes fine until the last steps. It is stuck there forever. I left it running all night and in the morning was still running on these steps. The Excel file has 100 rows (not much).

```
copying to [dbo].[table1]...
copying to [dbo].[table2]......
copying to [dbo].[table3]
```

All steps above complete successfully (100%) but these 3 does not even start.
The Microsoft Office I'm using is 32 bit so I use 32 bit Import and Export wizard. My operating system is windows 8.1. I also tried on windows 7 but still same thing happen.

If anyone has any ideas please reply to this post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you copying data from a workbook instead of a single spreadsheet?  It may be that the import simply does not know what to do with the blank spreadsheets also contained in the workbook.

Thanks

Jeff